# Nextcloud Server restart broken

Tags: kubernetes, nextcloud

i'm using Nextcloud Version 21.0.0 in a container(kubernetes). The problem is that as soon as I redeploy the container nextcloud wants to reinstall. These directories are saved on external volumens:
mariadb/mysql
config-direcotry
data
themes
But still the nextcloud app doesn't recognize that it's already installed.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you certain the directories are mapped properly?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.